# javascript constructor from parent class object

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, overriding

I'm trying to rewrite some part of wechat miniprogram (based on webview). There is an api provided to create canvas context:

```
CanvasContext wx.createCanvasContext(string canvasId, Object this)
```

I want add some methods to this CanvasContext object, while I dont have access to the source code, so I:

```
const CanvasContext = wx.createCanvasContext(canvasId, thisArg).constructor;
class MyCanvasContext extends CanvasContext {
        hello() {
                return 'world';
        }
}
```

I want use object created by the api to initialize MyCanvasContext, like:

```
let ctx = wx.createCanvasContext(canvasId, thisArg);
let myCtx = new MyCanvasContext(ctx);
```

What's the proper way to write the constructor of MyCanvasContext to load existing ctx into this? Hopefully not deep clone the original :p

Answer (score 0):

It will works only if `wx.createCanvasContext` is a constructor function:

```
class MyCanvasContext extends wx.createCanvasContext {
        hello() {
                return 'world';
        }
}

let myCtx = new MyCanvasContext(canvasId, thisArg);
```

Comment: thanks for answering, wx.createCanvasContext would return CanvasContext object, so I use that object's constructor as base class

Comment: So, does my solution works for you or need some fixes?

Comment: I need a proper way to create MyCanvasContext object from CanvasContext instance, clone ctx into myCtx

Answer (score 0):

Just figure the best way to will be:

```
constructor(obj) {
        super();
        Object.assign(this, obj);
}
```